# Getting 401 token error with Azure Active Directory SSO

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, openid-connect, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm trying to setup Azure AD SSO to authorise users to log into AWS. I believe I have things mostly set up, I get the Microsoft login option & after logging in I get the error `Invalid request 401 - error getting token`.

I've tried everything I can find that might be wrong but to no avail, does anyone have any clue as to what might be misconfigured?

Comment: Have you configured role in AWS and used client secret and Id for provisioning role

Comment: This  error  can occur  if  the SAML response from the identity provider does not has the role  attribute name set in  Name https://aws.amazon.com/SAML/Attributes/Role : Make sure to use the exact name of your role as role name (Name attribute) is  case sensitive. (Pascal cased).           RoleSessionName i.e; user.userprincipalname in  azure ad as above  which is typically a user ID or an email address. Its length can be 64 characters.